# How can a UML class template be represented in Grapviz dot

Tags: uml, graphviz, dot, pygraphviz

How can a UML class template node, like the one shown below, be generated in Graphviz dot?

[image: UML Class Template]

Answer (score 1):

Use html labels e.g.:

```
digraph top {
    N[shape=none label=<<table cellborder="0" border="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td color="none" colspan="2" width="90" fixedsize="true"></td><td border="1" rowspan="2" colspan="2" cellpadding="0" style="dashed" width="70" fixedsize="true">PARAM</td></tr>
    <tr><td sides="LT" border="1" colspan="2"></td></tr>
    <tr><td sides="LR" border="1" rowspan="2" colspan="3" width="150" fixedsize="true">ClassName</td><td width="10" fixedsize="true"></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td sides="LBR" border="1" colspan="3"></td><td height="8" fixedsize="true"><!--put height in seperate cell to avoid specify fixed width--></td></tr>
</table>>]
}
```

Rendered on viz-js.com:

[image]